# How do I restore Shift+MouseButton = select when mouse protocol is enabled in xterm 361?

Tags: mouse, xterm, clipboard

In `xterm`, in `vim` or other applications that can use the mouse in xterm, I used to be able to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to bypass that mouse button handling and do normal X selection.

With the latest update to xterm version 361 on Debian, that no longer works. In `vim`, Shift+LeftButton now seems to scroll down instead. After I enter `printf '\e[?1000h'`, I see that Shift+LeftButton sends something like `\e[M$xy` instead.

How do I revert to the old behaviour? Or what would be an alternative way to do normal X mouse selection in `vim` (or other applications that enable the mouse protocol)?

FWIW, I can reproduce even if I disable all customisations I can think of:

```
xrdb < /dev/null
env -i DISPLAY="$DISPLAY" xterm -class MYXTerm -name myxterm -e \
  vim -u NONE -c 'set mouse=a' -c help
```

(and try Shift+LeftMouseButton in that vim help screen).

Both with the xterm 361 Debian package and xterm built from source with the default settings.

**Edit**. After a reboot, the problem went away, but it was because that ended up deactivating NumLock. So, **correction**: the "problem" only occurs when I have NumLock on.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, turns out  the "problem" manifests  itself only when NumLock (mod2 modifier) is on.

Comment: That's expected: only the *shift* modifier (no other modifiers) in #361 allows bypassing mouse-protocol.  I might make that configurable...

Answer (score 4):

OP comments:

> turns out the "problem" manifests itself only when *`NumLock`* (**`mod2`** modifier) is on.

With [xterm #361](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_361), that is intentional:

> amend rule for using ***shift***-key to override *mouse-protocol* for *select/paste* to limit that feature to mouse-buttons which are actually bound to select/paste actions

xterm uses the [X Toolkit ***translations***](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xtoolkit/intrinsics.html#Translation_Management) resource to bind various keys and mouse (pointer) buttons with modifiers to actions.  Most people use the [default translations](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Default-Key-Bindings), possibly with a few additions in their X resources.  Because the translations feature is relatively static, xterm implements the [mouse protocol](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) by inspecting the events seen in the actions used for select/paste:

- [insert-selection](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:insert-selection)
- [select-start](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:select-start)
- [select-end](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:select-end)
- [select-extend](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:select-extend)
- [start-extend](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Actions:start-extend)

In #361 (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/bf04244e73fbf2792596bbd8246e1c208deac997/button.c#L390)), xterm checks the translations resource at startup, to determine which pointer (mouse) buttons are bound to these events, and when a matching button event is received with just the shift-modifier, it will override the mouse protocol and perform the select/paste action (as it has done for quite a while).

The reason for the change was to allow applications to get some combinations (such as *shift* with the wheel mouse) to receive escape sequences that they could interpret.

The translations resource does not describe this special treatment of shift, e.g., in

```
                       ~Meta <Btn1Down>:select-start() \n\
                     ~Meta <Btn1Motion>:select-extend() \n\
```

but xterm's mouse protocol relies upon being able to receive events which are not really explicitly defined in those translations.  I noticed after #361 that it did not treat *motion events* consistently with this altered scheme (and a fix will be in #362).

I generally use xmodmap to define a *Meta* key, so that I can use those translations.  With a display on macOS, I have this:

```
xmodmap:  up to 2 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x40),  Shift_R (0x44)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x41)
control     Control_L (0x43),  Control_R (0x46)
mod1        Alt_L (0x42),  Alt_R (0x45)
mod2        Meta_L (0x3f),  Meta_R (0x47)
mod3      
mod4      
mod5
```

while an unmodified xmodmap displaying on Debian is different:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

so that *Meta* is accessible in the latter, but less conveniently: it requires a couple of mode-switches.

There are other problem areas to explore, such as a pending pull request [*don't ignore missing non-standard modifiers in _XtMatchUsingDontCareMods*](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxt/-/merge_requests/45), which would interfere with the use of **`mod2`** for ***Meta*** (by eliminating some of those events which xterm converts into escape sequences).

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and very detailed answer. However, you lost me with the discussion about *Meta*. I understand `~Meta <Btn1Down>:select-start()` as meaning btn1 triggers `select-start()` unless the Meta modifier is on (mod2 for you, mod1 for me). I don't understand how that can allow me to do selection with shift and numlock on. I don't understand the *couple of mode-switches* part either. I can't test Alt+Btn1 as that's intercepted by my window manager to move windows.

Comment: After switching to a different window manager, after `\e[?1000h`, I see `\e[M(xy` upon Meta+btn1 (with numlock or not), `\e[M,xy` with Meta+Shift+btn1 (with numlock or not), and again `\e[M$xy` with Shift+btn1 (with numlock only). I don't see any other option but to disable numlock to be able to do mouse selection with Shift.

Comment: FWIW, according  to https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Normal-tracking-mode, xterm understands **mod1** as Meta, which is consistent with those `(` (0b10**1**000) and `,` (0b10**1**100) above when I press Alt.

Comment: It does that, in mouse-button events, however for other inputs (such as function-keys), I'd rather distinguish *alt* and *meta*.  I suppose this is another opportunity to improve the FAQ.  It's not clear to me why you're pressing numlock.

Comment: My keyboard, and all the keyboards I've used in the past 30 years always have had arrow keys separate from the numeric keypad, so I've never found any use for the numeric keypad other than for entering numbers, so I typically have numlock always on. Before moving to Scotland I used to live in France, and on a French keyboard, you typically enter sequences of digits via the numeric keypad as otherwise you need to hold shift to enter digits, so again numlock is typically on. Having to turn numlock off to be able to do mouse selection in xterm361 has become a major inconvenience to me.

Comment: I see (thanks for the clarification).  I'll add yet-another-feature in 362 to make the equality-check optional, so that the older/laxer check would be the default.  By the way, this is another case where that [pull request](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/jannh/libxt/-/commit/a44739378d5446f7b934c282cbb994599003d358) would create a problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell whether mod2 (or mod3...mod5) is on or off, that makes no different with regards to the mouse protocol, (the same sequence is sent regardless), so wouldn't it make sense to ignore those when deciding whether to bypass mouse protocol or not (as in Shift + btn does mouse selection as long as Ctrl/Meta are *not* on, regardless of the state of the other modifiers)?